# Frequent outofbounds with index in cellForRowAtIndexPath - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Frequently when I pull up on my `UITableView` to refresh the content drawn from my server it will crash with the following message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (4) beyond bounds (4)'
```

Now the issue is, my data on my end is set into an `NSDictionary` with the same data every time, so I know my server is not returning anything that is out of place.

Here how everything is working, I have an integer called `i`. `i` will always = 0 at repopulation of cells based on:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        //end of loading
        //for example [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        i = 0;//<!-- reset the i so that when page reloads cells it does not fail
    }
}
```

I am also adding on `2` extra slots for my `NSDictionary` because slot `0` and `1` are crucial pieces.  There associated with user information that populates the first 2 cells:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times"] count] + 2;//<!-- by default we want to make sure 2 is being added no matter what. 1 = clients address and name, 2 = upcoming lawn care
}
```

So back to `i` the first 2 calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I use `if statements` to assign the collected data for the first 2 cells. Than I increment `i` as I populate the other cells with data `(if any)`

Here is exactly what is going on within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];// Get rid of speration border color

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"homecell";

    HomePageTimelineCell *cell = (HomePageTimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[HomePageTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [cell initTimelineCell];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];// Set the background color to the cell

    // lets check if there is any data
    if([self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times"] == nil && [self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming"] == nil)
    {
        //<!-- if the indexRow row = 0, this is the clients username and address
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            NSArray *get = [[SSKeychain allAccounts] init];
            NSString *username = [get[0] objectForKey:@"acct"];
            //<!-- Get keyname of the address and than point to that keyname and get data
            //NSString *KeyName = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
            //<!-- create uppercase strings
            NSString *upperCaseAddress = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"client_address"] uppercaseString];
            NSString *upperCaseUsername = [username uppercaseString];
            //<!-- Set associated strings
            cell.addressLabel.text = upperCaseAddress;
            cell.usernameLabel.text = upperCaseUsername;
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"666666"];
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"];
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

        [cell.button setTitle:@"schedule" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"666666"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        /* Setup button action */
        //[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(onCustomAccessoryTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.dateLabel.tag = indexPath.row + 100; //<!-- 100 = date
        cell.dateLabel.text = @"Nothing Scheduled";//<!-- Set the Date
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.nextLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dayLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dateLabel];
        }
    }
    else
    {

    //<!-- Set background color
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"77d1af"];
        //<!-- Set background and text color for even cells
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"666666"];
    } else {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"];
        //<!-- Set background and text color for even cells
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffffff"];
    }
    //<!-- if the indexRow row = 0, this is the clients username and address
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSArray *get = [[SSKeychain allAccounts] init];
        NSString *username = [get[0] objectForKey:@"acct"];
        //<!-- Get keyname of the address and than point to that keyname and get data
        //NSString *KeyName = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row + 4];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseAddress = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"client_address"] uppercaseString];
        NSString *upperCaseUsername = [username uppercaseString];
        //<!-- Set associated strings
        cell.addressLabel.text = upperCaseAddress;
        cell.usernameLabel.text = upperCaseUsername;
    }
    //<!-- if the indexRow row = 1, this is the 2 cell and will show the most upcoming lawn schedule
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        //<!-- Lets check if user even has an upcoming mowing date -->
        if([self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming"] == nil)
        {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"666666"];
            cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"];
            cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell.button setTitle:@"schedule" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"666666"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            /* Setup button action */
            //[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(onCustomAccessoryTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            cell.dateLabel.tag = indexPath.row + 100; //<!-- 100 = date
            cell.dateLabel.text = @"Nothing Scheduled";//<!-- Set the Date
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.nextLabel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dayLabel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dateLabel];
        }
        else
        {
            //<!-- create uppercase strings
            NSString *upperCaseDay = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_day"] uppercaseString];
            //<!-- create uppercase strings
            NSString *upperCaseDate = [[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_date"] uppercaseString];

            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"666666"];
            cell.button.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"7ddcb8"];
            cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

            [cell.button setTitle:@"change" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"666666"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            /* Setup button action */
            //[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(onCustomAccessoryTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            cell.dayLabel.text = upperCaseDay;//<!-- Set the day
            cell.dateLabel.tag = indexPath.row + 100; //<!-- 100 = date
            cell.dateLabel.text = upperCaseDate;//<!-- Set the Date
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.nextLabel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dayLabel];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dateLabel];
        }
    }
    else //<!-- Normal cell population
    {
        //<!-- Re edit labels positioning
        cell.dayLabel.frame = CGRectMake(9, 10, 200, 45);
        cell.dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(9, 35, 300, 45);
        //<!-- Setup data called from server
        NSDictionary *innerClientData =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times"][i];
        NSString *innerClientDay =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times_day"][i];
        NSString *innerClientDate =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times_date"][i];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseDay = [innerClientDay uppercaseString];
        //<!-- create uppercase strings
        NSString *upperCaseDate = [ innerClientDate uppercaseString];

        //<!-- Check to see if client paid
        if([[innerClientData objectForKey:@"client_paid"]  isEqual: @"0"])
        {
            NSString *amount = [innerClientData objectForKey:@"client_price"];
            NSString *pay = @"pay $";
            NSString * combined = [pay stringByAppendingString:amount];

            [cell.button setTitle:combined forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if([[innerClientData objectForKey:@"client_paid"] isEqual: @"1"])
        {
            [cell.button setTitle:@"PAID" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        //[cell.button setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"666666"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
        /* Setup button action */
        //[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(onCustomAccessoryTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.dayLabel.text = upperCaseDay;//<!-- Set the day
        cell.dateLabel.tag = indexPath.row + 100; //<!-- 100 = date
        cell.dateLabel.text = upperCaseDate;//<!-- Set the Date
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.button];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dayLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.dateLabel];

        i++;

    }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

My assigning of the `NSDictionary` looks like:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"responseString: %@",responseString);
            // GRAB STATUS OBJECT
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData //1

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
self.dataGrabed_dictionary = [json objectForKey:@"retrieved_data"];
```

Suggestions as in why it crashes with `out of bounds`?

Comment: Where does it crash? You didn't point out which line of code is crashing.

Comment: Why is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so complicated but `numberOfRowsInSection:` is so simple? They don't appear to agree.

Comment: Is `i` and instance variable? Get rid of it. It should be `indexPath.row - 2`.

Comment: And why does the title reference `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but your question shows everything except that method?

Comment: I agree - you can't use `i` in the way you are - there is no guarantee as to which order `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called or that it will only be called once for each cell in the table - it will be called as the table scrolls, so your `i++` will eventually cause an array bounds issue

Comment: @rmaddy I believe you are right `indexPath.row - 2` is what I was missing because `i` was screwing things up based on every time you would increment.

Comment: Also @rmaddy, should much of my code be in `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: @DavidBiga No, your `numberOfRowsInSection` should be fairly simple. It just seems that the logic for populating rows in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't quite match the calculation for the number of rows. It might be OK depending on your data.

Comment: @rmaddy could you give me some insight to what seems strange to you?

Comment: The first `if` statement in `cellForRow...` isn't handled in `numberOfRowsIn...`. The end result may be the same but it may not be depending on the data.

Comment: I think it seems quite verbose.  Some of this is related to the programmatic creation of your cells (this is a personal preference thing, but I would use different UITableViewCell subclasses and prototype cells in IB - even if you don't use IB you an still create UITableViewCell subclasses that manage the various UI elements).  You could probably also make it easier to read by splitting into smaller methods

Comment: So in the long run it would probably be better to pass my `dictionary` values to a subclass cell creator and handle the data inside there, hence when the `cellForRo...` calls for `HomePageTimelineCell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is the way you get the data for the cells. You are using the instance variable `i` on the following lines:

```
    NSDictionary *innerClientData =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times"][i];
    NSString *innerClientDay =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times_day"][i];
    NSString *innerClientDate =[self.dataGrabed_dictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_times_date"][i];
```

That will never work. Replace `i` with `indexPath.row - 2`.

Cells can be accessed multiple times and in various orders.